# Concatenating String Arrays in For Loops with String conditions

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I currently am running a for loop which reads a List object and then splits them into arrays. Here is the sample code:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("foo,foo,foo","bar,baz,foo","foo,baz,foo", "baz,baz,baz", "zab,baz,zab");
    for (String line : lines){
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        String[] arraySplit2 = array[0].split(",");
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arraySplit2));
    }
```

The output is:

```
[foo][bar][foo][baz][zab]
```

I wish to concatenate the array strings into a single one under the loop so that it displays:

```
[foo, bar, foo, baz, zab]
```

I'm having a bit of trouble because the conditions of the loop prevent me from doing the increase int i trick and using `System.arraycopy()`. I'm open to ideas such as changing the structure of the loop itself.

Comment: Do you want to ignore duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to create an array out of first items from each line.

First, So you need to create the result array first with the size of number of lines:

```
String[] result = new String[lines.size()];
int index = 0;
```

You do not need the second split, in the for loop populate the result array:

```
   result[index++] = array[0]
```

**After** the loop print your result array.

Comment: When I employ this method, it seems that I get the following 
code  
`for (String line : lines){  
         String[] array = line.split(",");  
         String[] result = new String[lines.size()];  
         int index = 0;  
         result[index++] = array[0];  
         System.out.print(Arrays.toString(result));  
     }`  
output:
`[foo, null, null, null, null][bar, null, null, null, null][foo, null, null, null, null][baz, null, null, null, null][zab, null, null, null, null]`

Comment: Move lines result = new... and index = 0 before the loop. Move print after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on what you want, but I guess something like this:

```
List<String> outList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String line : lines) { 
    String[] array = line.split(",");
    outList.add(array[0]);
} 
String[] outStr = outList.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outStr));
```